# Angular JS - loading a controller from a JS file

Tags: angularjs

This controller works just fine:

```
function airlineRouter($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/',
            {
                templateUrl:"partials/destinations.html",
                controller: function($scope) {
                    $scope.setActive('destinations');
                } //end controller
         });
} //end airlineRouter
```

When I make the controller it's own JS file, it doesn't work anymore. Like this:

```
function airlineRouter($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        when('/',
            {
                templateUrl:"partials/destinations.html",
                controller: "DestinationsCtrl"
            });
} //end airlineRouter
```

My Controller file resides in 'root/js/controllers/destinations.js', which is the same folder my 'app.js' file resides. The complete 'app.js' file looks like this:

```
 angular
    .module('airline', ['ngRoute'])
    .config(airlineRouter);

function airlineRouter($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/',
            {
                templateUrl:"partials/destinations.html",
                controller: "DestinationsCtrl"
            }
        );
} //end airlineRouter
```

My complete controller JS file looks like this:

```
function DestinationsCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.setActive('destinations');
} //end DestinationsCtrl
```

Why won't my controller load by the function name as this tut I'm doing says? The tut's file seems to work. Mine isn't.

Edit: console log shows this: Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'DestinationsCtrl' is not a function, got undefined

Edit 2: The tut I was working on was called 'Nesting Scopes', if that gives anyone a better idea of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: what is your loading order?

Comment: one suggestion is set use convention of `var app=module('airline'...`  then for controllers `app.controller('DestinationsCtrl', function($scope)...`

Comment: oops...`var app=angular.module('airline'...` left out `angular`

Comment: `Changecontroller: "DestinationsCtrl"` to `controller: DestinationsCtrl`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, like I said, I'm new to AngularJS, and I'm kind of an idiot. I wasn't putting my external JS script links in my `<head>` on my index.html file. That's it. I can't believe I overlooked this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your controller declaration:

```
angular.module('airline')
       .controller('DestinationsCtrl',function($scope){
         $scope.setActive('destinations');
       });
```

Then this controller will work as expected.

Hope this is helpful for you.

Comment: The whole purpose of this part of the tut was to show the controller can be in an external/separate file. My first example works, but once I move it to an external file (see the path above), it's not seeing it. It seems like a really great way to manage/reuse logic. I'm just stuck.